# React Compile Error - Unexpected token (34:58) a.data.[field] !== undefined && b.data.[field]

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've Recently joined a company and have been given access to the source code of a project which fails at compile time however, according to the lead developer there's nothing wrong and I've been instructed to setup the project properly.

You can see the ERROR below:

[image: You can see the ERROR Below]

I'd really appreciate if someone can guide me if there's anything wrong at my side or if provide me with the solution.

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be

```
a.data[field] != undefined && b.data[field] != undefined
```

not

```
a.data[field] != undefined && b.data.[field] != undefined
```

on line 34